# Obtaining an unexpected p-value of 1.0 when comparing two identical time-series in Granger causality test with Python

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, time-series, associations, statsmodels

I have two time-series that I want to statistically test one is associated with another, accounting for some unknown time lag. I am new to time-series comparisons, so I am following this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/granger-causality-and-vector-auto-regressive-model-for-time-series-forecasting-3226a64889a6).

In my code below, I have a `df` with `x` and `y` which are numerical values. However, since the values in `y` is 100 to 1000+ times more than `x` over time, I would not expect statistical test to show that they are similar or identical.

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import grangercausalitytests

maxlag = 10
test = 'ssr_ftest' # options are 'params_ftest', 'ssr_ftest', 'ssr_chi2test', and 'lrtest'

df = df[['date', 'x', 'y']]
df['x_v2'] = df['x'] + 1

var_pair_p1 = ['x', 'x']
var_pair_p2 = ['x', 'x_v2']
var_pair_p3 = ['x', 'y']

test_result_p1 = grangercausalitytests(df_merged[var_pair_p1], maxlag=maxlag, verbose=False)
test_result_p2 = grangercausalitytests(df_merged[var_pair_p2], maxlag=maxlag, verbose=False)
test_result_p3 = grangercausalitytests(df_merged[var_pair_p3], maxlag=maxlag, verbose=False)

p_values_p1 = [round(test_result_p1[i+1][0][test][1], 4) for i in range(maxlag)]
min_p_value_p1 = np.min(p_values_p1)
max_p_value_p1 = np.max(p_values_p1)
mean_p_value_p1 = np.mean(p_values_p1)

p_values_p2 = [round(test_result_p2[i+1][0][test][1], 4) for i in range(maxlag)]
min_p_value_p2 = np.min(p_values_p2)
max_p_value_p2 = np.max(p_values_p2)
mean_p_value_p2 = np.mean(p_values_p2)

p_values_p3 = [round(test_result_p3[i+1][0][test][1], 4) for i in range(maxlag)]
min_p_value_p3 = np.min(p_values_p3)
max_p_value_p3 = np.max(p_values_p3)
mean_p_value_p3 = np.mean(p_values_p3)

print('p-value of {}: min={}, max={}, mean={}'.format(test, min_p_value_p1, max_p_value_p1, mean_p_value_p1))
print('p-value of {}: min={}, max={}, mean={}'.format(test, min_p_value_p2, max_p_value_p2, mean_p_value_p2))
print('p-value of {}: min={}, max={}, mean={}'.format(test, min_p_value_p3, max_p_value_p3, mean_p_value_p3))
```

Output

```
 p-value of ssr_ftest: min=1.0, max=1.0, mean=1.0
 p-value of ssr_ftest: min=1.0, max=1.0, mean=1.0
 p-value of ssr_ftest: min=0.0, max=0.0257, mean=0.00413
```

My understanding is that p-value<0.05 indicates that one time-series Granger causes the other. Or as I interpret it as the two time-series are similar or identical if lag is not a factor.

If that's the case, why am I not getting p-value<0.05 for `var_pair_p1 = ['x', 'x']` and for `var_pair_p1 = ['x', 'x_v2']`? Conversely, why am I getting p-value<0.05 for `var_pair_p3 = ['x', 'y']` while `x` and `y` are expected to be unrelated?

Comment: I guess that's because the second series provides no **additional** information given the own history/lags of the first time series. But I'm not sure whether degenerate cases like identical time series are handled properly by grangercausalitytests.

Comment: The matrix of regressors in the auxiliary regression should be singular and have reduced rank if both series are perfectly collinear. In that case inference is not "reliable", I'm not sure what happens in that case with the granger causality test.

Comment: So if I have 2 time series (with potential time lag), while they are not the same, I want them to be statistically not different. Is Granger causality test suitable, or other tests more appropriate?

Comment: If you want to test whether the two time series are "similar", then granger causality doesn't help. Granger causality means that a time series helps you to predict a second time series beyond what you could do with the second time series alone. Two times series not being "statistically different" requires a definition for similarity which would depend on the context, e.g. one case could be if they are cointegrated, another case would be high correlation at some lag.

Comment: Do you mind naming the tests that can show two time series to have high correlation with possible lags?